# Sencha Touch 2 painted event not firing

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I built a view and I want to do some manipulation of the elements, after the view has been painted.

I am trying to use the "painted" event with no avail.

Any ideas why?

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.phone.RegisterViewPhone', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    xtype: 'RegisterViewPhone',

    config: {

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'Header'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                itemId: 'thePanel',
                html: 'THIS WILL HOLD THE VIEWS CONTENT'
            },{
                xtype: 'Footer'
            }
        ],

        listeners: [
            {
                delegate: '#thePanel',
                event: 'painted',
                fn: 'onPainted'
            }
        ]
    },
    onPainted: function () {
        alert('hey!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach listeners to that particular element like

```
   {
        xtype: 'panel',
        itemId: 'thePanel',
        html: 'THIS WILL HOLD THE VIEWS CONTENT',
        listeners: {
            painted: function(){
                alert('hey!');
            }
        }
    }
```

As painted is not dependent on individual element and it acts on page scope also U can write it in views directly

```
items: [
 ],
 listeners: {
 painted: function () {  
   alert('hey!');
 }
```